# MonoTouch/MonoDroid community license?

Tags: licensing, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Does anyone know if Xamarin will be making community licenses available for open source projects or library publishers to test compatibility? Who can I contact to ask for them?

Comment: You can test in an emulator using the trial version. Unfortunately you can't test a program on a real android device without a license currently. Not even on your own phone while debugging :( No idea if there is a planned offer for non commercial / open source / students etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Xamarin support, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a "Contact Us" form on the site of [this page](http://xamarin.com/support). A little hidden, but they responded pretty quickly. Thanks! The answer is that you can download the trial version to run anything in the emulator, but that a commercial license is required for testing on a device.

No response about an open-source/community license.